# Select a line equal to 'X' without TOP 'N' plus the previous line 'Y' in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return in a query only the last lines with 'ProductStatus' equal 'Stop' and the previous line.

I have the table:

[image]

And need to get this result:

[image]

How do I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Which column should we us for ordering?

Comment: Data as an image really doesn't help us help you. If you provide it as text we can consume it and help you. Please do also show us what you've tried, as it may be as simple as a typographical error that you got wrong when you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions to calculate the last stop and then get the row before that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(seqnum_ps) over (partition by producttype order by datevalue) as next_seqnum_ps,
             lead(status) over (partition by producttype order by datevalue) as next_status
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by producttype, product_status order by datevalue desc) as seqnum_ps
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where (seqnum_ps = 1 and product_status = 'Stop') or
      (next_seqnum_ps = 1 and next_product_status = 'Stop');
```

An alternative method gets the maximum stop time and uses that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when product_status = 'Stop' then datevalue end) over (partition by producttype) as max_stop_dv,
             lead(datevalue) over (partition by producttype order by datevalue) as next_dv
      from t
     ) t
where datevalue = max_stop_dv or
      next_dv = max_stop_dv;
```